# Set title to an element with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I want to do is to apply a specific title to any element with a specific class.

**HTML**

```
<span class="br">BR</span>
<span class="dvd">DVD</span>
<span class="br">BR</span>
<span class="br">BR</span>
<span class="sc">Sc</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
}
.br{
    background: blue;
}
.dvd{
    background: green;
}
.sc{
    background: black;
}
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anndresorozco/Ld8wZ/1/)

How can I set a title to any element with the class "br"? Is it better to do it with jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by “title”? A `title` attribute, or a visible caption, or something else?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I mean title attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it with jquery. CSS is a presentation language. It isn't designed to add content, aside from `:before` and `:after`

Jquery:

```
$('.br').attr('title','yourtitle');
```

Comment: No clue. It's the correct answer if I'm not mistaken. I assume you're the one that upvoted it. I appreciate it!

Comment: This is the correct answer if the question is about adding a `title` attribute, though jQuery is just one way of doing things in JavaScript. But adding `title` attributes is rather pointless; if the purpose is to produce tooltip effects, then CSS tooltips are much better.

Comment: I'll do it with jQuery. And yes, I meant to add a title attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.br').attr("title","your title attribute goes here");
```

Comment: I mean title attribute.